# Excel crashes when setting column widths of a listbox (in VBA) during a userform initialisation

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

**The Problem:** My MS Excel crashes intermittently every time I try to load a userform ("MS Excel has Stopped Responding") specifically when setting column widths of a listbox.

**The Background:** Using a write to text file style logger I've managed to narrow the problem down to a section of code where this is happening (when it does happen) but I can't seem to see any obvious issues with my code. It seems to be happening when I am initializing a userform from a command button on a spreadsheet, more specifically when my code is setting the column widths of a number of listboxes on the userform.

**The Code:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim strUserName As String
Dim strUserNameF As String
Dim headerARR() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

logevents (Time() & " - Loading form...")

strUserName = Environ("Username") 'for a more specific user log on number
strUserNameF = Application.UserName 'for a UI friendly log on name

'Set Labels
lblLoggedInAs.Caption = "You are currently logged in as: " & strUserNameF & " (" & strUserName & ")"
lblCurrVersion.Caption = "Current Version: " & strCurrVersion
lblLastUpdated.Caption = "Last Updated: " & strLastUpdated

logevents (Time() & " - Variables Set; Creating Tables")
Application.StatusBar = "Variables Set; Creating Tables"

logevents (Time() & " - Creating Table lbSearchTermResultsIPActions")
With lbSearchTermResultsIPActions
    .ColumnCount = 4
    .ColumnWidths = "25,50,48,150"
End With

logevents (Time() & " - Creating Table lbIPActions")
With lbIPActions
    .ColumnCount = 11
    .ColumnWidths = "40,1,28,72,70,32,53,98,60,70,70"
End With

logevents (Time() & " - Creating Table lbMyActions")
With lbMyActions
    .ColumnCount = 8
    .ColumnWidths = "44,1,47,61,127,60,50,35"
End With

logevents (Time() & " - Creating Table lbOutActions")
With lbOutActions
    .ColumnCount = 8
    .ColumnWidths = "44,1,47,61,127,60,50,35"
End With

logevents (Time() & " - Creating Table lbAllActions")
With lbAllActions
    .ColumnCount = 8
    .ColumnWidths = "44,1,47,61,127,60,50,35"
End With

logevents (Time() & " - Creating Table lbSearchTermResults")
With lbSearchTermResults
    .ColumnCount = 15
    .ColumnWidths = "25,50,50,150,100,70,70,85,50,40,65,40,40,40,40,40"
End With

logevents (Time() & " - Tables Created")
Application.StatusBar = "Tables Created"
```

**The Output:** In my log it gets to the below stage each time then crashes, though again, it does not always crash, and if I enter the VBA window then hit the button the amount of times it does happen are dramatically reduced. (No sure if this is useful info or not?)

```
17/11/2015 15:21:45 S***    15:21:45 - Loading form...
17/11/2015 15:21:45 S***    15:21:45 - Variables Set; Creating Tables
17/11/2015 15:21:45 S***    15:21:45 - Creating Table lbSearchTermResultsIPActions
```

I have tried to search here and on other forums but haven't really come across any definitive solution. I have tried putting a 1 second `Application.wait` after each listbox and of course tried the code without all of the write to log functions, but neither have seemed to have any effect.

**Update:**
So I've tried to initialise the user form first; press a button on a sheet to open the user form - setting the listboxes (from design instead of code now), then have a button that processes the rest of the initialise code (setting drops downs, filling listboxes with data etc) on the user forms first tabbed page. This appears now to crash MS Excel once the second button has been pressed whilst trying to do a simple loop to populate a combo box.

**Added as per Davids request:**

```
logevents ("Starting first loop")

For i = 1 To 6
    With Controls("cbField" & i)
        .Clear
        .List = Array("", "Action_Status", "Action_Urgency", "Action_Territory", "Action_Team", "Action_Owner", "Action_Stage", "Action_Due_Date", "Attorney")
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With

Next i
```

Change events linked to combo boxes:

```
Private Sub cbField1_Change()

Select Case cbField1.Value

    Case ""
        cbOption1.Clear

    Case "Action_Urgency"
        With cbOption1
            .Clear
            .List = Array("Low", "Mid", "High")
'                .ListIndex = 0
        End With

    Case "Action_Territory"
        cbOption1.Clear
        rsARR = GetUniqueDepts
        For i = LBound(rsARR, 2) To UBound(rsARR, 2)
            cbOption1.AddItem rsARR(0, i)
        Next
        Erase rsARR

    Case "Action_Team"
        cbOption1.Clear
        rsARR = GetUniqueTeams
        For i = LBound(rsARR, 2) To UBound(rsARR, 2)
            cbOption1.AddItem rsARR(0, i)
        Next
        Erase rsARR

    Case "Action_Owner"
        cbOption1.Clear
        rsARR = GetUniqueOwners
        For i = LBound(rsARR, 2) To UBound(rsARR, 2)
            cbOption1.AddItem rsARR(0, i)
        Next
        Erase rsARR

    Case "Action_Due_Date"
        With cbOption1
            .Clear
            .List = Array("Due", "Overdue")
'                .ListIndex = 0
        End With
'            Erase rsARR

    Case "Attorney"
        cbOption1.Clear
        rsARR = GetUniqueAttorneys
        For i = LBound(rsARR, 2) To UBound(rsARR, 2)
            cbOption1.AddItem rsARR(0, i)
        Next
        Erase rsARR

    Case "Action_Status"
        cbOption1.Clear
        rsARR = GetUniqueActions_Required
        For i = LBound(rsARR, 2) To UBound(rsARR, 2)
            cbOption1.AddItem rsARR(0, i)
        Next
        Erase rsARR

    Case "Action_Stage"
        With cbOption1
            .Clear
            .List = Array("Open", "Closed")
'                .ListIndex = 0
        End With

End Select

End Sub
```

I really don't know what's going on here, could it be that my user form is too complex and MS Excel just can't handle all the procedures at once as I do have a few operations that run on first opening the user form?

Comment: pls try to do a `.Clear` of each listbox first and check if the problem still pops up

Comment: I'm not sure it should crash, but the separator should be a semicolon rather than comma and for the last control you have 16 widths for 15 columns. Why aren't you setting these items at design time?

Comment: oh true... try to set width with: `.ColumnWidths = "25 Pt;50 Pt;28 Pt;150 Pt"`

Comment: The .Clear didn't seem to do much unfortunately. 
@Rory - Just out of habit I guess, I'm using it to display table results from an SQL query so I set the table up in code in case I need to change it at a later date or during use. I am testing out setting these at design time now and so far no problems. Will update with progress.

Comment: @DirkReichel Tried setting the widths at design time and also setting them in code using your suggested formatting. Still getting random crashes on start up. Seems to also be happening with all other users in my office that have tried my workbook.

Comment: *This appears now to crash MS Excel once the second button has been pressed whilst trying to do a simple loop to populate a combo box.*  Can you show the code for this loop?

Comment: The only i can think of is that the workbook itself has an error... that means that you need to create a new workbook... however, copy worksheets or forms may also copy the error... you' d need to create just the part that are causing the error (form + macro) and test it several times... If the error doesn't pop up, then copy each part and always run tests between. Hmm... have you tried to use `Application.EnableEvents = False` in front of the code? (I'll delete my answer for now)

Comment: @DavidZemens Added the code for where it is now crashing on the loop

Comment: If the `cbField#` controls have event procedures like a `_Change` event, we need to see that code, too...

Comment: @DirkReichel Added the bitof code you suggested Dirk, still no joy. Maybe worth mentioning that if I open the VBA window (using Alt+F11) first and then run the program as normal pressing the button on the welcome sheet, Excel doesn't crash at all.

Comment: @DavidZemens I've added the change events code, the `rsARR = GetUniquexxx` creates a database connection and using an SQL query, basically retrieves a list of options to populate the drop downs with. I can paste this also upon request (but as previously mentioned, if I run this with the VBA window open, it all runs fine with no problems throughout use)

Comment: Do you realize that assigning `ListIndex = 0` to the `cbField#` controls, this will trigger a change event in `cbField#`, subsequently raises a change event (if one exists) in `cbOption1` control?  So then we would need to see *that* code (and please note taht code may be triggering additional events, so we would need to see *that code, too*, etc., etc., etc...). What it sounds like, to me, is that you do not understand how the controls interact with one another, and specifically when their events may be raised, and you are taking no precautions to prevent events when you don't want them to.

Comment: ight now i can't think of anything except the chance there is a bug in the workbook itself... when running the code without events and having the crash at different parts of the code but only "sometimes" doesn't sound like a typo or something like that... there is still the chance of a different process which messes up the ram or something like that (but that would also cause other errors)... so there may also be the database-connection holding corrupt data.... i don't think it is an easy answer... leaves only the option of creating a new wb as a test :/

Comment: @DavidZemens I do realise that, and it is intentional. The code is there to first populate the first set of combo boxes with the code defined variables, then it sets a default value for the combo boxes (which in this case is blank), this will set the change event for the option (related) combo box. In the event of a blank (our default value) the combo box is cleared. No more events take place (cbOption1 has no 'on events') I set a value as blank on start up so that no unnecessary db connections are made. Please let me know if I have missed something else?

Comment: Your form *probably* isn't more complicated than [this PPT Add-In of mine](http://i.imgur.com/Q0BclfH.png), which has about 30k lines of VBA across 5 user forms and ~40 modules & class modules :)

Comment: Export all modules and user forms to disk, then import the modules & forms to a *new* XLSM workbook. Does the error persist?

Comment: @DavidZemens Problem still persists after exporting all modules forms and class modules into a new WB. Though now it appears to be crashing constantly when I am hiding (in vba) certain tabs on my main form that is initializing, which is just after the populate combo box code section.

Comment: Until you can provide an MVCE , I can't possibly be of any further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Through testing numerous scenarios I discovered that whilst the workbook is open,  Saving the workbook before running any code prevents any excel crashes that I was experiencing without any adjustments to my original code.

I simply added:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

To automate the process.

*Note: Wanted to add this as an answer, though it is more of a workaround so I will not mark it as THE answer, but thought it may be useful to post as an answer for people who are also experiencing this problem and come across this thread.*

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but this problem still exists on macOS.
The workaround above did not work for me.

What did work was setting the column widths *after* the list is loaded.
With no data, any attempt to set the widths would take out Excel completely.

Under Windows there are no issues setting the columns.